# How to use Nike Running with iOS 8's Health app?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

I installed iOS 8 on my iPhone 5S today and the got the Health app as a result.

It shows on the Health app that it can get data when the app "sends" data over to the Health app.  So I assume Nike Running (an app from Nike) probably has that built in?  If so, how can the running / walking data be sent over to iOS 8's Health app?

P.S. ok, I saw news headline such as: Apple seemingly removing HealthKit compatible iOS 8 apps from App Store due to issues, and Apple's health monitoring app is DOA: Firm forced to stop apps from using feature as it admits to iOS 8 bug

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too. There's a nike fuel area but I have no idea how to connect it to my Nike account or the app. This could be due to the bug that were announced today.

Answer (score 6):

Nike (and all the others providing similar things) needs to update their application to make use of HealthKit and send data to the Health app.

Apple has announced that these updates also will not be available until later in September 2014:

- http://www.loopinsight.com/2014/09/18/apple-pulls-healthkit-apps-after-discovering-last-minute-bug/